# Data manipulation in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I understand this may be a very simple question, however I'm new to python and I'm unsure how to manipulate pandas data frames very well.

**Lets say as an example data:**

```
   Job                Skill                   RelationType
 Director            Manage staff                essential
 Director            Manage  staff               optional
```

**Target**

**Lets say as an example data:**

```
   Job                Skill                   RelationType
Director            Manage staff                essential
Director            Manage  staff               essential
```

Ideally I want to write a function that when the RelationType is different but the Skill is the same it overwrite and replace by in this case for the essential. So for the same job a essential skill will be always more important than the optional.

### Solved

```
df['RelationType'] = df.groupby(['Jobs', 'Skill'])['RelationType'].transform('min')
```

Comment: How do you define which RelationTypes are prioritized in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/categorical.html) is useful for this task. First convert `RelationType` to a categorical series, ordered with more prioritised values first.

Then perform a `GroupBy` operation by key fields, using the `min` function to choose the most prioritised category.

```
df['RelationType'] = pd.Categorical(df['RelationType'], ordered=True,
                                    categories=['essential', 'optional'])

df['RelationType'] = df.groupby(['Job', 'Skill']).transform('min')

print(df)

        Job        Skill RelationType
0  Director  ManageStaff    essential
1  Director  ManageStaff    essential
```

Comment: tks for the guidance, I had to change a bit to work.. But thanks for providing me with a new tool... very good this function transform df['RelationType'] = df.groupby(['Jobs', 'Skill'])['RelationType'].transform('min')